# Subversion 1.1.4: How do I add a file that is labeled as not currently under version control?

Tags: svn

I accidentally added a few files to my working copy directory, and when I run an svn status they are labeled with a question mark (item is not under version control). I'd like to correct this by adding the files to version control, but I'm not sure what the consequences are of deleting the files and attempting to svn add them. Can anyone recommend the best approach? Thanks.

Comment: "deleting the files and attempting to svn add them" - why do you want to delete them? `svn add` should do what you want without having to delete them first

Comment: ... and you mean 1.*7*.4? 1.1.4 is really old

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use `svn add <file>`, even after the files have been created.  If you delete them, the repository will remain unchanged.  Only by adding files and committing them will you alter the repository.